# looping through a data table vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I'm trying to loop through a data table that has multiple values for my constraint.  How can I keep the first value and add together all the other values that match my constraint.

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("TEND_POS_ID") = 8 Then

              'This only returns the last value  
              'Value 1 = 2
              'Value 2 = 7.5
              'should = 9.5 but it is showing 7.5                  

             tmpCoupon = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("TENDER_AMT")
            End If
        Next
        txtCoupon.Text = tmpCoupon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to add the values of `TENDER_AMT` where the value in `TEND_POS_ID` is 8. If this is the case you could use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method of the DataTable

```
 Dim rows = ds.Tables(0).Select("TEND_POS_ID = 8")
 for each r in rows
    tmpCoupon += Convert.ToDecimal(r("TENDER_AMD"))
 Next
```

However, rembember that this kind of work (SUM a column grouping by another column) is usually better resolved by the query that you submit to the database. Something like this:

```
SELECT TEND_POS_ID, SUM(TENDER_AMD) FROM Table1 GROUP BY TEND_POS_ID
```

Comment: not sure if this helps, but its a stored procedure that I have no control over.  tmpCoupon is already a Decimal value.  Yes, i'm trying to add the values of TENDER_AMT where the TEND_POS_ID = 8.  Looping through the DataTable and printing the values via Debug.Print works, but how can I add them (addition) together.

Comment: Yes, the code above executes the addition `tmpCoupon += ` however, it the field is a decimal I need to fix the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I tried it this way before.  It works now.